# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal use in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to create a `confirmation-dialog-header` directive that will open a [Bootstrap UI Modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) that will be used like this:

```
<button class="btn" confirmation-dialog-header="Non Working Dialog">
  Non Working Dialog
</button>
```

Here is what I'm trying to do (CoffeeScript): [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/inayip/1/edit)

```
app.directive 'confirmationDialogHeader', ->
  restrict: 'A'
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    $confirmationDialog = $ """
      <div modal="confirmationDialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>#{attrs.confirmationDialogHeader}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          I want to be hidden by default
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn" ng-click="confirmationDialog = false">
            OK
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    """

    $(document.body).append($confirmationDialog) 

    $(element).click ->  
      scope.confirmationDialog = yes
```

Unfortunately, the modal is not hidden by default, and clicking the button doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When dynamically inserting DOM elements containing AngularJS directives, you need to [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) them to kick in AngularJS.
2. In event callback, [`scope.$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) need to be invoked to trigger AngularJS evaluation loops.

Thus

```
app.directive 'confirmationDialogHeader', ($compile) -> # 1

   $(document.body).append($confirmationDialog) 
   $compile($confirmationDialog)(scope) # 1

   $(element).click ->  
     scope.confirmationDialog = yes
     scope.$apply() # 2
```

[Working One](http://jsbin.com/inayip/4)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `dialog` service.  To hide the modal in your directive, wrap the entire dialog in a `<div>` with the classes `hide,modal,fade`.

Comment: It looks like you are writing your own directive for bootstrap.  I'm suggesting you use the one the angular team has already written.

Comment: My directive should have some confirmation logic. What you suggest doesn't provide that. I need a custom directive that uses the `modal` directive they provide.

Comment: Look at the JavaScript on the project page, you can see up buttons and capture results from the dialog.  A dialog can have its own controller which could do verification and then pass the results back to the parent controller

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look. But, still, I would be interested to know why the code above isn't working as expected.

Comment: See my update, I think you are missing a class on the modal header.